Using uploaded data across JavaScript Modules
I am working on a project that simulates generic sports matches. I am trying to add functionality where a user can upload/save teams to the project. To organize the scripts, I have separated various functions into different modules and am coordinating the overall functionality through main.js:
const uploadTeamButton = document.getElementById("upload-team-button");
uploadTeamButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const loadTeamInput = document.getElementById("team-upload");
  const upload = uploadTeamJSON(loadTeamInput).then(
    () => {
      console.log(upload);
      allTeams = addTeam(upload, allTeams);
      displayTeamsAtSelect(allTeams);
    }
  );
  closeOverlay();
});

The function uploadTeamJSON() is defined in the module load-write-data.js:
export async function uploadTeamJSON(upload) {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  let newTeam = {};
  let uploadJSON = {};
  async function readFile() {
    const data = fr.result;
    console.log(data);
    uploadJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(uploadJSON.name + " uploaded.");
  }

  fr.readAsText(upload.files[0]);

  fr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    readFile().then(() => {
      newTeam = newTeamInput(
        uploadJSON.name,
        uploadJSON.seed,
        uploadJSON.streakType,
        uploadJSON.streakLength,
      );
      console.log(newTeam);
      return newTeam
    });
  });
}

This is the result in the console once the Upload button is clicked in the Web View:
{
  "fileType": "team",
  "simVersion": "1.2",
  "name": "Test Team 1",
  "seed": 5,
  "streakType": "W",
  "streakLength": 1
}
Test Team 1 uploaded.
Object {name: "Test Team 1", seed: 5, streakType: "W", streakLength: 1}

The issue I am having is that the code defined in .this() after uploadTeamJSON() in main.js appears to be running too early and is processing an undefined Object. The console.log doesn't even get executed. I am fairly new to JavaScript so I may be missing something, but shouldn't the code wait until uploadTeamJSON() is finished processing?

I wouldn't call it "upload" if you're not sending any data to your server. It's an import from a file into your web application.

You wrote two async functions but never awaited anything in them. You just started reading the file and added an event listener.
